# START WITH using exists condition in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to use start with clause to get hierarchical data in Oracle. I have the below two tables :

TableA (schema) (6 million rows ):
id, cost

TableB (schema) (35 billion rows):
id, parent_id

We want go from Table A , get all the parent_ids associate with the id recursively. Something like the query below :

```
Select * from TableB START WITH id in ( select id from TableA ) 
connect by id = prior parent_id and parent_id != id
```

While the above one works for small number of rows for TableA, i'm trying to do this where TableA has 6 million rows and TableB has 35 billion rows.

Whats the recommended way to get hierarchical data in this case ( something like exists clause ) ? Trying 'between' also generates a lot of id's which is not required ..

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the condition on TableA going to be like?!

Answer (score 0):

With that big data set, you need to filter well on what are you selecting from TableA

You query is correct but requires a condition on TableA

```
select * from TableB
start with id in ( select id from TableA where <condition on TableA>) 
connect by id = prior parent_id and parent_id != id
```

Most important is that:
- TableA has index on the column(s) you're going to use to filter on (the condition)
- TableB has primary key or unique key on ID

If your query ended up using an index on TableA (and retrieves selective not large number of columns), and using UNIQUE key on TableB, then it should perform well.

However, I have calculated average records in B for each record in A to be ~6,000 records!

If you need to reduce the set of records retrieved by TableB, then you better do this before the connect by

```
 select * 
 from (select * TableB where <condition to be applied before connect by>)
 start with id in (select id from TableA where <condition on TableA>)
 connect by id = prior parent_id and parent_id != id
```

Practically, such large volumn of data should always be properly partitioned, which you mentioned nothing about